# Mouse Event Runs Multiple Times

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

it's a Rectangle inside a Grid in my program

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="mainGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" MouseEnter="rectangle_MouseEnter" Focusable="True" MouseLeftButtonDown="rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeave="rectangle_MouseLeave" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Margin="2" Stroke="Transparent"/>

</Grid>
```

and mouse left button down events:

```
private void rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("mouse left button down on rectangle");
    }

    private void mainGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("mouse left button down on mainGrid");
    }
```

it's output when mouse button downs on rectangle:

> mouse left button down on rectangle
>
> mouse left button down on mainGrid

I want just rectangle mouse event rise up when click in rectangle, and grid mouse event rise up when click outside the rectangle

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MouseLeftButtonDown` is [bubbling event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742806(v=vs.100).aspx#routing_strategies) which means it will go up the visual tree from originating element. You can limit the execution of the handler by setting `Handled` to true in `rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown`

```
private void rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    Debug.WriteLine("mouse left button down on rectangle");
}
```